# I would like to populate an email message with the contents of a specific, static, cell in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am sending a confirmation email when someone signs up for an appointment on a Google form. I would like to have the email message be populated with the contents of a specific cell. This means I would be able to type an email message into cell A2 and when someone fills out a form, it will send that message to them as the confirmation email.

I have two different email messages I am using, confirmation email and reminder email. I would like both codes to populate the same message.

```
function confirmationEmail(e) {
   var userName = e.values[2];
   var userEmail = e.values[3] + ";user@gmail.com";
   var date = e.values[4];
   var studentName = e.values[1];
   var body1 = "Hello " + userName + ",";
   var body2 = studentName + " has been registered for a physical at High School for the following date/time:";
   var body3 = "Please park in the large student parking lot on the east side of the High School.";
   var body4 = "Thanks!";
   var signature = "Name" + "\n" + "High School" + "\n" + "user@gmail.com" + "\n" + "***-***-****";
   var file1 = DriveApp.getFilebyId("1WDxic1meHzEGSjybJ2SS1h2MqGAhIAK4");
   var file2 = DriveApp.getFilebyId("1v4GQAP8PkTPQRPoYIdsEOMBr2ZvRO1eocsqixyZ42gA");


GmailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 
                     "Registration",
                     body1 + "\n\n" + body2 +"\n\n" + date + "\n\n" + body3 + "\n\n" + body4 + "\n\n" + signature,
                     {attachments:[file1, file2]})

}
```

This code works perfectly already, however, I have some co-workers even less savvy than I. It would work best if they could just fill in the cell with the contents of the message to be able to send this out. So ideally, "body3" would be written into a cell within sheets and populated into the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess you would want something like this:

```
var body3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').getValue();
```

You should probably include some conditional statements in the code to prevent the sending of the email in the event that cell 'A2' is blank and include an alert to inform the user that it needs to  be filled in.

Perhaps something like this:

```
if(body1 && body2 && body3){
  //send email
}else{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Invalid or Missing Content');
}
```

- [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)